# Inconsistent DynamoDB writtings

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

We have the following code used as lambda Function in Serverless Framework triggered every 2min with cron. The issue we are facing is that the writing in DynamoDB is inconsistent , we want to have 3 writings but instead we receive 1 or 2 writings every 2 minutes.
DynamoDB has a HASH key the HOUR and SORT KEY the DATE and Billing mode: PROVISIONED. Has someone faced the same behavior from DynamoDB or the same issue to share how he sovled it. Thanks

```
"use strict";

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const axios = require("axios");

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
  region: "us-east-1",
});

module.exports.getWeather = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const openWeatherMapAPIURL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${event}&appid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&units=metric`;
  const currentWeather = await axios
    .get(openWeatherMapAPIURL)
    .then((records) => {
      console.log(records);

      const d = new Date(records.headers.date);
      let hour = d.getHours();

      const params = {
        TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME,
        Item: {
          hour: hour,
          date: records.headers.date,
          city: records.data.name,
          temp: records.data.main.temp,
          feelsLike: records.data.main.feels_like,
          description: records.data.weather[0].description,
        },
      };
      setTimeout(function () {
        dynamoDb.put(params, (error) => {
          // handle potential errors
          console.log(`zapis na: ${records.data.name} ${records.headers.date}`);
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.error(error);
            return;
          }
        });
      }, 3000);
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    });
 

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: `Weather from ${event} was requested!`,
    }),
  };
  callback(null, response);
};

module.exports.cron_launcher = (event, context, callback) => {
  const requestedID = ["786735", "792578", "785842"];

  requestedID.forEach((requestedID) => {
    const params = {
      FunctionName: process.env.HANDLER_LOCATION + "-getWeather",
      InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
      Payload: JSON.stringify(requestedID),
    };

    return lambda.invoke(params, function (error, data) {
      if (error) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        return new Error(`Error printing messages: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
      } else if (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the dynamodb.put operation to finish. Additionally, you are wrapping the call in a setTimeout. Your lambda function is returning before the network operation can be made. Make sure the put operation succeeds before returning a result from your lambda.

1. I see no reason for you to use a setTimeout here.
2. You can call dynamodb.put(...).promise() to get a promise from the dynamodb SDK and await that promise.
   2.a Or you can continue using a callback, but wrap the entire section of code in a new promise object, calling the resolve method after the dynamodb.put call finishes.